# Error:Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android-studio, github-api, android-glide

**Build.gradle(Module:App)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.beetel.App"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"



    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
   maven{ url "https://jitpack.io"}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //glide libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.3.1@aar'
    //            { transitive = true;}
    //            { exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp';}
    //compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    //retrofit,square,rxjava libraries
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta4'
    //android support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    //    compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:23.2.0'
    //    compile 'net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    //    compile project(':AndroidBootstrap')
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.1.8'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.3.0'
}
```

**Build.gradle (Project:App):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
//        maven{
//           url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"}
//        maven
//                {
//                    url "http://dl.bintray.com/florent37/maven"
//
//                }

        }
    }


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.beetel.App">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.example.beetel.App.utilities.ConfigGlide"
            android:value="GlideModule"/>
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.beetel.App."
            android:name="com.example.beetel.App.data.model.MoProvider"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.beetel.App.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.beetel.App.MoDActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_modetails"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.beetel.App.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Detail">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.beetel.App.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am not able to understand why the error is coming again and again?
I want to implement glide palette to have more effective UI.
I tried to invalidate caches/restart,rebuild project,clean project etc.
Please help me...stuck with this not able to debug further.Deadlines approaching..
Thanks in advance!

**Message after Gradle Build**
[image: Message after Gradle Build]

Comment: anyone face similar issue with glide??

Answer (score 4):

In Build.gradle (Proyect app) add this

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
    maven  {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
  }
}
```

In Build.gradle (Module app) add the dependency     **com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0**

```
dependencies {

...
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
...

}
```

Comment: I have already tried that before..but its not helping...Please Check Image I have added It might help you to understand problem better...will wait for your response.....

Answer (score 3):

I too faced the same error. Add these lines to the repo and sync the project.

Worked for me like a charm.

```
repositories {
              mavenCentral()

              jcenter() 
              if (project.hasProperty('local.repo'))
              {
                maven { name 'glide-local'; url project.property('local.repo') }
              } 
              maven { name 'glide-snapshot'; url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
              flatDir name: 'libs', dirs: 'libs'
             maven 
             {
                url "https://jitpack.io"
             }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks man it actually helped to sort SNAPSHOT issue but other   issue related to Glide arises...such as Error:error: cannot find symbol method centerCrop(),Error: cannot find symbol method error(int),Error: cannot find symbol method diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy) (Note:some methods related to Glide api is not working.)...have u Faced any of these issues?

Comment: Yeah I have faced! For center crop I changed the xml attribute scale type of image view to center crop
    


      android:scaleType="centerCrop" 



But I donno about diskCacheStrategy because I never used it

Comment: well mine is different case from you I am facing this issue while using it as Glide method as explained on  Glide library  official readme doc.Well I think this is some issue with Glide Library in my case..well if i found anything regarding your problem...will update you with it?..Happy coding!!

Comment: @PN10 I am facing the same problem, did you find any solution to it?

Comment: @Nobody I sort the issue somehow but don't remember exactly but I think the issue was snapshots versions ,so I remove the dependencies for snapshots and check the link it might help: http://bumptech.github.io/glide/dev/snapshots.html  and http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and fixed it by putting these lines in build.gradle(Module: app)

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}
```

and it fixed

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. If you have this error it's because you need to use jitpack.io to use -SNAPSHOT.

So u just have to copie  this :

```
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

in your file build.gradle(Module: app)
if you never touch this file it look like this :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
```